# loop that count to 100 and replace with some text any number that divide by 3 or conatins number 3

Tags: javascript, loops, replace

```
function checker (num){
  for(i = 1; i <= num; ++i){
    if(i % 3 === 0 ||
       i === 13 ||
        i === 23 ||
         i === 33 ||
          i === 43 ||
           i === 53 ||
            i === 63 ||
             i === 73 ||
              i === 83 || 
              i === 93){
      console.log('boom')
    }
    else{
      console.log(i)
    }
  }
}
checker(100)
```

so i made this , but thats looks ugly , how to do it correct ? like any number that contains 3 replace it with some text. thank you.

Comment: Turn your number into a string a check for "3"

Comment: please add some use case what you really want. should the number contain `3` or should be divisible by three or/and have a last digit of three?

Comment: any number that contains 3 like 3,13,23,33 and numbers that can be devided by 3 , like 3,6,9,12,15,18 @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your loop only counts to 100, you only need to check the tens and ones place to determine if it's a `3`. You can use the JavaScript [modulo operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modulo-or-remainder-operator-in-java/) `%` and the `Math.floor()` [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor):

```js
if (Math.floor(i / 10) === 3 || i % 10 === 3 || i % 3 === 0) // ...
```

The `Math.floor` method will return true if dividing the number by 10 and rounding down returns 3 (`true` for the numbers `30` to `39` inclusive), and the `%` modulo operator will return `true` when dividing `i` by 10 has a remainder of `3` (true for `3`, `13`, `23`, `33`, etc.) `i % 3 === 0` is from your original function.

Comment: thank you for adding explanation for this its very helpfull , never thought it that way .. math ))

Answer (score 2):

You could check the string, too.

```
if (i % 3 === 0 || i.toString().includes('3')) ...
```

Comment: This seems to incorrectly return `true` with some numbers that don't have a 3 in them—like `6` and `42`—due to `i % 3 === 0`.

Comment: @Brooke, it comes from `i % 3`. this part is coming from op.

Comment: You're correct; my apologies. Your code doesn't appear to check the code's first digit, though, which is what I assumed the OP meant by `any number that contains 3`.